# how to use two hashmap arraylist in one activity?

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-fragments, android-studio

Guys i am working on an android project when i use two Hashmap arraylist in one activity than my application crashed.i am working on it from last two days but problem is still here. i tryed all solution and debug program and study all step very deeply.

```
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList;
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList1;
```

arraylist1 is not working until i comment arraylist. i cant understand the problem please suggest any solution.

java code....

```
public class Dashboard extends Activity {
    public static Dashboard_Adapter adapter;
    public static list_adapter list_adapter;
    ListView listview;
    ListView Listnewpost;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
public static final String like_count = "like_count";
public static final String name1 = "name";
String like;
public static String name11;
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList;
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList1;
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dashborad);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvcomment);
    Listnewpost= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvShowPost);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList1= new ArrayList<>();
    new dash_board().execute();

}


private class dash_board extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Dashboard.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while your request is in progress.....");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }



@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        int success;
        JSONObject response;
        int returnCode;
        //String result = "{\"Response\":{\"ReturnCode\":200,\"ReturnMessage\":\"Information Successfully Retrieved\",\"ReturnData\":null,\"ReturnClass\":{\"PRO_ID\":\"11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111\",\"PRO_FirstName\":\"SILVER\",\"PRO_LastName\":\"HIYO\"},\"FriendlyErrorMessage\":null}}";
        String data1 = "[{this is a flat json}];



       try {
            Log.d("hy one ","two");

            JSONArray jr=new JSONArray(data);

            HashMap<String, String> arre;
            for (int i=0;i<jr.length();i++) {
                jsonObject = jr.getJSONObject(i);
                like = jsonObject.getString(like_count);

                arre = new HashMap<>();
                arre.put("like_count", like);
                arrayList1.add(arre);
            }

                JSONArray jsonArray3=jsonObject.getJSONArray("comments");
                HashMap<String, String> arr;
                for(int j=0;j<jsonArray3.length();j++){
                    arr = new HashMap<>();
                    JSONObject jsonObject3 = jsonArray3.getJSONObject(j);
                    name11=jsonObject3.getString(name1);
                    Log.d("name value",name11);

                    arr.put("name",name11);
                    arrayList.add(arr);
                }

            Log.d("arraylist", String.valueOf(arrayList1.get(0)));


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        list_adapter= new list_adapter(Dashboard.this,arrayList1);          
        adapter=new Dashboard_Adapter(Dashboard.this,arrayList);


        listview.setAdapter(adapter);


       Listnewpost.setAdapter(list_adapter);



    }
}
```

Comment: Show more code about ` arrayList` and `arrayList1` please

Comment: please post your java code

Comment: Also, if you could show the stack trace when the app crashes, that would be nice too.

Comment: I think the problem would be inside your code where you are using this hashmap so share your code for better understanding.

Comment: Have create instance for both the map's..?

Comment: please check updated code

Comment: why do you want to use static..?

Answer (score 0):

Do Something like this

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, String> stringStringHashMap = new HashMap<>();
    stringStringHashMap.put("key1","Hello 1");
    stringStringHashMap.put("key2","Hello 2");
    stringStringHashMap.put("key3","Hello 3");
    arrayList.add(stringStringHashMap);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, String> stringStringHashMap1 = new HashMap<>();
    stringStringHashMap1.put("key1","Hello 1");
    stringStringHashMap1.put("key2","Hello 2");
    stringStringHashMap1.put("key3","Hello 3");
    arrayList1.add(stringStringHashMap1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Hashmap's above of onCreate() method, instead of creating inside onCreate() method(i.e.,Make hashmap's global).

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList1 new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```